# Renderscript getFieldID_ exception (for ScriptGroup)

Tags: renderscript

I am trying to put two RS filters in a script group. I've tested both scripts and they work as intended. The input of each filter is a global allocation. However, an exception thrown when I try to get the fieldID of any of the allocations:

```
//[..] Script object has been created 
Script.KernelID kernelID = mBox3x3.getKernelID_filter(); // this works
Script.FieldID field = mBox3x3.getFieldID_gIn(); // this throws
```

The exception trace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptCThunker.thunkCreateFieldID(ScriptCThunker.java:224)
            at android.support.v8.renderscript.Script.createFieldID(Script.java:130)
            at com.example.android.basicrenderscript.ScriptC_boxFilter3x3.getFieldID_gIn(ScriptC_boxFilter3x3.java:61)
```

The script is a simple 3x3 box filter. The .rs file is:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.android.basicrenderscript)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed
rs_allocation gIn;
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) filter(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
[...]
}
```

Do global fields need a particular flag? What am I missing? Thanks!